# How to display text in center of the page in mpdf

Tags: php, mpdf

I want to display text in center of the page. But, it's not display proper. I used mpdf and i want to display using mpdf in php.

**What I tried :**

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap.php';

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();

$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullwidth');
$stylesheet = '<style>' . file_get_contents('example1.css') . '</style>'; // external css
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet, 1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<div id="center">
Hello World
</div>', 2);
$mpdf->Output('filename.pdf');
```

**CSS :**

```
#centrar{
    margin:0;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #000;
}
body { text-align: center }
```

**Output :**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zftFf.png)

It's display center in first line. I want to display in full page center part.

How to do that? Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: One way to do it is to output using a table at 100% width and height and use vertical-align: middle

Comment: Can you please add code in answer?

Comment: I'm on phone at the moment so cannot test any code. Google "html table css vertical align"

Comment: id="center", is not #centrar... And there is plenty of tutorials how to center everything on world wide web...